# Use of modal logic in metaprogramming

Tags: reference-request, modal-logic, metaprogramming

I know modal logic has been experimented with for formalizing macros and metaprogramming before but I am not really familiar with the details. I would like to read up more on the use of modal logic for macroes and metaprogramming. Does anyone have some good references?

I have a hunch metaprogramming could help with foundational issues like predicativity and finitely axiomizable theories but I don't really know where to start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Contextual Modal Type Theory](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Efp/papers/tocl07.pdf)

> The intuitionistic modal logic of necessity is based on the judgmental notion of categorical truth.
> In this paper we investigate the consequences of relativizing these concepts to explicitly specified
> contexts. We obtain contextual modal logic and its type-theoretic analogue. Contextual modal
> type theory provides an elegant, uniform foundation for understanding meta-variables and explicit
> substitutions. We sketch some applications in functional programming and logical frameworks.